# How to set a custom roundup in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create in excel that rounds up a certain cell range according to the multiple of number 80 (For example if I entered in one cell 75 it will automatically round it up to 80 or 120 to 160 ...etc) and another range by the multiples of the number 100 (For example 80 -> 100, or 130 -> 200)

Comment: to be honest, I want a help to this, no matter the exact way (Desperation here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value you want to round up is in `A1` and the multiplier is 80, you can use:

```
=ROUNDUP(a1/80,0)*80
```

Replace 80 with 100 for the second option.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I want it done once I enter the data in the cell this might work if it was on another cell